# Not able to use the keyword 'message' as a parameter in Custom Ansible Module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

We have a Custom Ansible Module which have been written by us. In that module, we have 4 parameters as module arguments:

- `message_direction`
- `external_request_id`
- `message`
- `protocol`

```py
def run_module():
    # defining available arguments/parameters a user can pass to the module
    module_args = dict(
        message_direction=dict(type='str', required=True, choices=['sent', 'received']),
        external_request_id=dict(type='str', required=True),
        message=dict(type='str'),
        protocol=dict(type='str', required=True)
    )
```

But if we using the keyword `message` it is causing an issue when we run a playbook script in command line with `ansible-playbook` command.

**Getting these type of errors:**

```
...ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 1989, in log\nTypeError: send() got multiple values for keyword argument 'MESSAGE'\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
```

But instead of using the keyword `message`, if we use any other keyword name like  `message_data`, `message1`, `message2` etc. it is working fine. Is there any restriction on using `message` as module parameter in a Custom Ansible Module?

Note: `message` parameter is working fine if we run it in Python script with Ansible Python library. Only when we run in command prompt with `ansible-playbook` command we are getting the error.

Comment: What is your exact Ansible version? Based on that, you could go and have a look at the incriminated file source code at the line pointed by the error message: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py, just switch to the branch that correspond to your version.

Comment: But, yes, you can see for yourself that this utils is using `MESSAGE` https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/b63812bc08fd00fd772c28a2604f77f487d23104/lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py#L1342, now does it crash on you because of this or because of something specific in your module, this is hard to tell without the full message traceback and / or your exact version and / or a [mre].

Comment: Hi @β.εηοιτ.βε I am using 2.9 version. Yes, seems like we can't use 'message' as parameter. It is kind of restricted keyword I think so. Got some info from these 2 links.
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/60051
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/68000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the exact example from [Developing modules - Creating a module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html#creating-a-module) and [Developing modules - Verifying your module code](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html#verifying-your-module-code) it is was not possible to reproduce the behavior.

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Custom Module Test
    test:
      name: "{{ NAME }}"
      new: true
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: result
```

For a given `--extra-vars="NAME=Hello"` or `--extra-vars="NAME='fail me'"` resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show result] *********************************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  result:
    ansible_facts:
      discovered_interpreter_python: /usr/bin/python
    changed: true
    failed: false
    message: goodbye
    original_message: Hello
```

or

```yaml
TASK [Custom Module Test] ************************
fatal: [test.example.com]: FAILED! => changed=true
  message: goodbye
  msg: You requested this to fail
  original_message: fail me
```

But it is possible to get the example failing, if the argument paramenter names gets changed. Because of the

```yaml
from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule
```

the error

```
TypeError: send() got multiple values for keyword argument 'MESSAGE'
```

seems relating to [lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py#L1337), lines 1337 to 1363. Therefore you may consider `MESSAGE` as a restricted argument parameter name in your case.

**Further Documentation**

- [Ansible module architecture - Passing args](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_program_flow_modules.html#passing-args)
- [Ansible module architecture - AnsibleModule](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_program_flow_modules.html#ansiblemodule)

added from OP comment

- [Replace 'message' in module parameters](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/60051)
- [Module TypeError: send() got multiple values for keyword argument 'MESSAGE'](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/68000)

Comment: @SuryaN, for a more detailed answer it will be necessary that you provide the full custom module code, the relating playbook and the resulting outputs. As well your used versions of Ansible, Python, OS, etc.. At least a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for putting efforts on this.
I am using 2.9 version. Yes, seems like we can't use 'message' as parameter. It is kind of restricted keyword I think so. Got some info from these 2 links. github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/60051 github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/68000